# How to hide a div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. Everything work, but I also want to hide extand div if I click him.For example I click button 3 and div extands and I click one again and div hide contain. I try everything but it doesn't work. I wrote many function but it doesn't I hope someone help me. This function in javascript is OK, but I have to add some code that div hide contain.

```js
          function showHide(obj) {
  const nextObj = obj.nextElementSibling;
  const dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll('.drop')
  dropDowns.forEach(e => {
 
     e.style.display = 'none';
  })
    nextObj.style.display = 'block';
     
}
```

```css
.iptv{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
background-color:blue;
margin-bottom:10px;
color:white;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.drop{
    background-color:green;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
    <body>
<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button1</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button2</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button3</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button4</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: follow w3school . you can check the link  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click

Comment: It doesn't work I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code snippet, the `nextObj.style.display = 'block';` has no conditionals so even if you click on the `button` again, it will always set the `element` to `block`.
Here is the solution

```js
var count = 0;
function showHide(obj) {
  const nextObj = obj.nextElementSibling;
  const dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll(".drop");
  dropDowns.forEach((e) => {
    e.style.display = "none";
  });
  if (count % 2 == 1) {
    nextObj.style.display = "none";
    count++;
  } else {
    nextObj.style.display = "block";
    count++;
  }
}
```

```css
.iptv{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
background-color:blue;
margin-bottom:10px;
color:white;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

.drop{
    background-color:green;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button1</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button2</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button3</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button4</div>
<div class="drop" style="display:none">
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use toggle()

```js
  function showHide(obj) {
    const nextObj = obj.nextElementSibling;
    nextObj.classList.toggle('displaydrop');
}
```

```css
    .iptv{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    color:white;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }

.displaydrop{
    display: none;
}
.drop{
    background-color:green;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

 
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button1</div>
<div class="drop displaydrop" >
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button2</div>
<div class="drop displaydrop" >
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button3</div>
<div class="drop displaydrop" >
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="down">
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv">Button4</div>
<div class="drop displaydrop" >
<a href="home">Home</a>
<a href="About">About</a>
<a href="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `.classList.toggle()` is absolutely the right approach, but if you are toggling classes like this, then you don't need inline styles like: `style="display:none"`. It would be cleaner to add these style declarations to the classes you are toggling.

Comment: Give Om EL a little time, @netjav - this answer is on the right track and with a little work it can be a model answer.